# Create a new column in pandas based on conditional text values from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

How to create a new column in pandas based on conditional text values from two other columns?

Initial table -

```
Specialty   Category  
Spec A      Cat A     
Spec A      Cat B     
Spec A      Cat C
Spec A      Cat D
Spec B      Cat A     
Spec B      Cat B     
Spec B      Cat C 
Spec B      Cat D
```

Conditional Logic =
Cat A and Cat D is not renamed as 'Others'
Cat B and Cat C renamed as 'Others'
No change in specialty.
new column to concatenate Specialty and Category based on the logic above.

This table to be output to -

```
Specialty   Category  Specialty_group
Spec A      Cat A     Spec A Cat A       
Spec A      Cat B     Spec A Other
Spec A      Cat C     Spec A Other
Spec A      Cat D     Spec A Cat D 
Spec B      Cat A     Spec B Cat A
Spec B      Cat B     Spec B Other
Spec B      Cat C     Spec B Other
Spec B      Cat D     Spec B Cat D
```

Comment: What is the condition logic?

Comment: @ it_is_Chris Conditional Logic = Cat B and Cat C and all other remaining Cat is 'Others'
Cat A will remain same. Have updated the question too.

Comment: `df['Specialty_group'] = np.where(df['Category'] == 'Cat A', 'Cat A', 'Other')`?

Comment: or are you looking for `df['Specialty_group'] = df['Specialty']+np.where(df['Category'] == 'Cat A', ' Cat A', ' Other')`?

Comment: Why does 'Spec A' become 'Spec'?  That isn't defined in your logic statement.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated logic and final output table now.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Im sorry I have now updated the logic and final output table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create a mask based on your logic
mask = (df['Category'] == 'Cat A') | (df['Category'] == 'Cat D')
# assign a values to a new column using loc and join
df.loc[mask, 'Specialty_group'] = df[mask].agg(' '.join, axis=1)
# assign values to a column using loc with the opposite of your logic
df.loc[~mask, 'Specialty_group'] = df[~mask]['Specialty']+' Other'


  Specialty Category Specialty_group
0    Spec A    Cat A    Spec A Cat A
1    Spec A    Cat B    Spec A Other
2    Spec A    Cat C    Spec A Other
3    Spec A    Cat D    Spec A Cat D
4    Spec B    Cat A    Spec B Cat A
5    Spec B    Cat B    Spec B Other
6    Spec B    Cat C    Spec B Other
7    Spec B    Cat D    Spec B Cat D
```

Comment: This is the cleanest method to get this done especially when I have more Cat in 'Others'.